# No event triggering on change in the UI

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, infragistics

I am working on a project, and we are using Infragistics as a third party control library. We have not provided with any documentation of the project and only thing I know is they have used MVP design pattern. Now I am trying to debug the application based on the task given to me.

I have a custom grid (mostly from Infragistics) and it has three columns "ColA, ColB, ColC". ColB and ColC have comboboxes. ColB and ColC already are bind to a datasource. When I change the selected item in the ColB combobox, based on the selection in ColB, ColC combo collection refines itself(removes few items based on the value in ColB). Here I need to change some logic in the collection refinement for ColC based on the ColB selected value. But I am not able to as I am not sure where the refinement is taking place. I tried placing the breakpoints, but there is no event triggering while changing the value in ColB and thus I dont know the codes related to refinement.

I know the question is specific to my project, but what my question is that is there any way to get to the codes based on the action taken by me in the UI apart from breakpoints? Or is there any approach I should be following in this situation? I am not very good in debugging tools.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone deep into the code to see how it actually works. For our project, all the controls are the custom controls that are created in a different solution all together. All these functionality are defined there for different kind of controls and that is the reason why no event was triggering while changing the selection. But if you change something in the custom control solution all controls of that type will be affected. For that reason they have they have even given a counter event attached to these custom controls. I will have to work on that. I know this was highly project specific query and as well as solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what event is used to update combobox in a cell. If yo have sources, check these UltraGrid events for refinement code.

Events fired **after** colB changed:

1. CellChange
2. AfterExitEditMode
3. AfterCellUpdate
4. AfterRowUpdate

Events fired just **before** user will see an expanded combobox of column colC:

1. BeforeEnterEditMode
2. BeforeCellListDropDown

Also try a small test. For example you have these dependencies between colB and ColC:

- B1 => C1a, C1b, C1c
- B2 => C2a, C2b

Set colB=B1 and colC=C1b. Now switch to another row, come back to this row and change colB to B2. If value in colC is changed, then you should look in events fired **after** cell change. If nothing happened  - your code may be in both groups of events.

Also you may try to search your code for a term *ValueList* - that code likely use this cell property.